# Way of interactively editing some text from the shell

Tags: shell

<strike>**Tl;dr**</strike> **Question**

Is there a nice way to interactively edit a string from the shell, storing the edited value in a variable.

Basically exactly like `a=$(cat "hello world" > /tmp/command &&  vim /tmp/command </dev/tty >/dev/tty && cat /tmp/command)` but without clearing my screen while editing (so that I don't lose my place and can still read output from previous commands).

I really want behaviour exactly like *imv* or *icp*, but I just want to get given the string back rather than moving or copying a file.

Or like `a=$(echo "hello world" | zenity --entry-text "$(cat)" --entry)` but without X.

This is rather an "I WANT A PONY" type question, but it feels useful in general situations.

**Context**

Stack exchange loves context, so here is my specific use case:

I love *zsh* line editing. I'm using it for a *zsh widget* to add parts of a command in my history to my current line like so:

```
strace <M-l h>
```

->

```
<LIST of history commands>
```

->

```
SELECT COMMAND
```

->

```
POP UP EDITOR
```

->

```
TWEAK COMMAND
```

->

```
strace command with lots of arguments some of which I want to edit
```

**Alternatives considered**

Make use of the shell's command-line editor and history (`!!`) to do what I want.

Using *zenity* `echo hello | zenity --entry-text -entry`  <- I don't really like using X

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: :/  I don't really know what to do to make it better... I mean I have an exact definition of what I want linking tools that provide features.

Comment: *linking to tools that provide very similar functionality

Comment: IMHO we don't need a "tl;dr" on Stack Exchange. Explain the problem.

Comment: @JeffSchaller So the "tl;dr" is actually the question I want answered / i.e. my problem. I mean... if I didn't include this "tl;dr" I wouldn't really be asking my question. My experience looking at stack overflow is that if you just ask just the question you want answered and don't include a bunch of context people moan / tell you to do things that you don't want to do. It's really the context I want to miss out. The intended purpose of the two sections is to split up "this is what I want" from "this is some background context"

Comment: readline edits the current command line, and you could edit the desired line to then say `a='that string'` and then you have the edited command-line in a string.  You want to edit, but without using an editor. I'm unclear on the question.

Comment: Hmm... this question might be a little too specific. So: i) I want to edit a particular string rather than the whole line, ii) I want to still me able to look at my terminal output / not lose my place while doing so. I don't care about using an editor: I just want to be able to read what's on my screen. *imv* is a good example of why this is useful. For a plausible compelling use case consider something like `a=$(ls | fzf); mv "$a" "$($MAGIC_EDIT $a)"` to select and rename a file. There's no nice way to do this with readline/zle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're describing something like the zsh `vared` builtin. It puts the current value of a variable into ZLE, and when you finish editing, the edited line becomes the new value of the variable.

```
% x=foo
% vared x
foo
```

[Do some edits to change `foo` to `bar` and press Return]

```
% echo $x
bar
```

Comment: Nice `vared` is precisely what I'm looking for. I thought there might be an executable that did the same thing. I would prefer to be able to do stuff like `$(vared-const stuff)` but I guess since I can achieve this with `b="$a"; vared b; "$b"` this is just me moaning.

Comment: `my-expand-history:vared:3: ZLE cannot be used recursively (yet)` :( . Looks like you can't use `vared` within widgets. For context here is my widget `my-expand-history() {# Insert a command from history command=$(fc -nl  | fzf); vared -p "Insert string:" command; LBUFFER+="$command";}`